# Is there a way to turn Async.js queue drain callback into a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, async.js

Is there any way to turn the [drain](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#queue) method into a promise so I can say something like `q.drain.then...`? Im using the `bluebird` library if that helps.

Comment: can `drain` be called more than once?

Comment: maybe if you add items after the q has already been drained

Comment: then promises are not useful

Comment: Please show us the code of your queue, and the characteristics of `push` calls. It depends on what you are doing with the queue for whether there's a good promise equivalent (if at all).